# How can I trick Minecraft into thinking two computers are on the same wifi network?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Minecraft's got an "Open to LAN" feature, which can be used to set up a local server when two computers running Minecraft are on the same network. Some young relatives of mine use this to play together whenever they're in the same house, but they'd like to be able to play together from their respective residences.

A server is not optimal because it's a bit complex. I've tried using Tunngle to spoof that the computers are on the same connection to no avail.

How can I convince Minecraft's "Open to LAN" that their two separate computers are on the same network?

Comment: I've never actually used it, but isn't this what Hamachi is for?

Comment: Use Hamachi or Tungle etc.

Comment: @Shinrai I think Hamachi is typically used to create minecraft servers without a portforward. The idea here is to use minecraft's internal option and not a full portforward.

Comment: @iananananan - By my understanding Hamachi is a VPN, so it should behave like a LAN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing Old LAN games over internet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59819/playing-old-lan-games-over-internet)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Hamachi, here's how I solved the problem.

Briefly:

- Join a Hamachi Network on both computers
- Hit Open to LAN on one (the host)
- Join `hamachi-ip:port` in direct connect Minecraft option, where port is the port listed by the host Minecraft when you hit Open to LAN, and the IP is the Hamachi IP of the host device.

Answer (score 6):

You need a VPN. [Tunngle](http://www.tunngle.net) is a good solution for games if you can deal with the ads, otherwise use [Hamachi](http://hamachi.en.softonic.com) if you're prepared for the possibility of having to deal with [configuring adapter priority](http://help.logmein.com/SelfServiceKnowledgeRenderer?type=FAQ&id=kA030000000DGHgCAO). Hamachi is a lot more friendly toward creating private networks, which is a plus if you don't want your server to be raided by strangers.

Comment: Using Tunngle, open to LAN showed nothing. What's the process?

Comment: @iananananan you need to join the same network.

Comment: In tunngle you can create a private network with your username and desired password. Your friend(s) can then search for your username in tunngle and connect with your set password. If they have connected succesfully you should see them in the lobby. Then they can connect with your local ip and port that minecraft provides on login.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma I seem to recall Tunngle being rather uncooperative when I tried to create a private network, perhaps this has changed in recent years.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet but http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1448177-minecraft-open-to-internet-v05/ looks interesting.

One side would run this program, and give the other side its internet IP and the port number, and then the other side should be able to connect as if it was a normal server.

Comment: The linked webpage requires you to be logged in to view its content. Can you quote the contents of the link in your answer?