# How do I play Minecraft with people online, besides using a server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to play on a survival world with a neighbor, but I cannot connect to his internet so how to play with him besides a server?

Comment: you could fool your computers to thinking your on a lan and play that way...

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149857/how-can-i-trick-minecraft-into-thinking-two-computers-are-on-the-same-wifi-netwo

Answer (score 4):

Using a program such as [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/download.aspx), you can fool your computers into thinking that they are connected to the same LAN network. Then, one of you can enter a single player world and select "Open to LAN" from the pause menu, which should allow the other to join.

Comment: Last time I checked (which admittedly was with version 1.4), Hamachi did not work with "Open to LAN" games. You have to get the server .jar or .exe from [minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/download), run it, and connect to your own server yourself (use *localhost* as IP)

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is no other way. Although one of you could host a server off of your computer (free of charge). There are plenty of videos on it.

Comment: "There are plenty of videos on it," isn't really a good answer. Particularly when this SE question comes up first on search results. It's like saying, "Thank you for searching this topic and clicking our link. Now go do it again and go to a different site instead."

Answer (score 0):

There are public servers, private servers and LAN servers, but the only other way is Minecraft Realms - which I think you need to buy.

Comment: Realms also isn even available in the US, if that is where you live.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how far the neighbor is from you, you could either use a LAN world or register a free server on https://aternos.org/ temporarily.