# Is it possible to play Minecraft Java edition with someone from a different area on a private server?

Tags: technical-issues, pc, minecraft-java-edition-server, hosting, windows

I'm trying to invite an online friend of mine to my private server, and they couldn't join while they're screen says "Unknown Host". Does it have to do with distance or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you both using the same version of minecraft? Is the ip correct? Are you or the other person running clients?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trick Minecraft into thinking two computers are on the same wifi network?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/149857/how-can-i-trick-minecraft-into-thinking-two-computers-are-on-the-same-wifi-netwo)