# Is to possible to play Roadrash multiplayer (mano-a-mano)?

Tags: pc, networking, road-rash

I tired to play this good old game with my friends which are located in different places via network gaming ("Mano A Mano mode")

But I couldn't connect it by using TCP / IP and IPX options also. I tried various combinations. Is this still possible?

I searched the Internet but there are almost no results available regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Road Rash for the PC doesn't natively support internet play. Like many games of its time period, the only officially-supported multiplayer configurations are LAN (TCP/IP or IPX) and 1-on-1 modem play.

However, as is the case with many LAN-only games, it's possible to play Road Rash over the internet using a LAN emulator. In fact, it's still listed on [Kali's compatibility list](http://www.kali.net/games.asp), though I'm sure there are other LAN emulator tools that will do the same job.

I also stumbled across [this older question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/59819/playing-old-lan-games-over-internet), which you might find helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..TCP/IP is internet play right?

Comment: Not necessarily, no. You're right that TCP/IP is one of the main transport protocols used on the internet today, but on a lot of older games, TCP/IP was just available as an alternative networking protocol setting you could choose (other than IPX) to play games over a LAN. I think it's often possible to make TCP/IP LAN support work over the internet with copious amounts of router tricks and port forwarding, but it's often pretty difficult, and only gets trickier the older the game in question is.